# A kind of foliation on figure eight knot complement

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, knot-theory, foliations

**Let $N$ be the figure 8 knot  complement, What we can say about such kind of dim 2 foliation $F$ on $N$: (1) no Reeb (2 dim); (2) $F$ intersect transversely with $\partial N$ is $n$ parallel Reeb (1 dim)?**

Here is a natural example. Let $T^2$ be a torus and $f=(2,1;1,1)$ be a diff on $T^2$. Suppose $(M,\phi_t)$ is the suspension of $(T^2,f)$, which is a transitive Anosov flow.  Then cut a standard small solid torus neighborhood of the closed orbit of 0, we obtain a manifold $N$ which is homeomorphic to figure 8 knot complement.  The stable manifolds of $\phi_t$ (restrict to $N$) give $N$ a dim 2 foliation $F$  which satisfies: (1) no Reeb; (2) $F$ intersects transversely  with $\partial N$ is two parallel Reeb.

This example  comes from the paper [link text](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0086986) where Franks and Williams constructed the first example of nontransitive Anosov flow.

**Can we construct more such kind of foliation? How?  Can we classify them in some sense? ...**

Comment: You might have a look at the thesis of Timothy Schwider: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8592391/dissertation.pdf



Comment: @Agol, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a Seifert surface which minimizes the Thurston norm in its relative homology class. (This exists because Seifert surfaces are not 0-homologous.) Gabai's Theorem says that every Thurston-norm minimizing surface is the leaf of a taut foliation. Taut foliations do not have Reeb components. [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-18/issue-3/Foliations-and-the-topology-of-3-manifolds/10.4310/jdg/1214437784.full)

Comment: @thku, thank you. But, I feel for figure 8 knot, since it is fibered knot, such a foliation intersect with the boundary torus maybe (at least, for the lowest genus seifert surface) pareller circles foliation (doesn't satisfy that  "$F$ intersect transversly with $\partial N$ is $n$ pareller Reeb (1 dim)"). 